# Heroku `Detecting rake tasks` not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake, ruby-on-rails-6

I upgraded my rails application from ruby 2.5.2 and rails 5.2.3 to ruby 2.6.3 and rails 6.0.
Everything work but I'm trying to deploy my application to Heroku (for the first time) and I have a problem.

This is the stack error on `git push heroku deploy`:

```
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote:
remote:  !
remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:  !     rake aborted!
remote:  !     ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:206:in `rescue in _decrypt'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:183:in `_decrypt'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:157:in `decrypt_and_verify'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/messages/rotator.rb:21:in `decrypt_and_verify'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:80:in `decrypt'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:43:in `read'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:21:in `read'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:33:in `config'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:38:in `options'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb:297:in `method_missing'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/config/application.rb:14:in `<class:Application>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/config/application.rb:9:in `<module:x>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/Rakefile:7:in `require_relative'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:29:in `load'
remote:  !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:29:in `<main>'
remote:  !
remote:  !     Caused by:
remote:  !     OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError:
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:201:in `final'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:201:in `_decrypt'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:157:in `decrypt_and_verify'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/messages/rotator.rb:21:in `decrypt_and_verify'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:80:in `decrypt'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:43:in `read'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:21:in `read'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:33:in `config'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:38:in `options'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb:297:in `method_missing'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/config/application.rb:14:in `<class:Application>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/config/application.rb:9:in `<module:x>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/Rakefile:7:in `require_relative'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_d247c4d10f4947cb3890930c1a9913cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:29:in `load'
remote:  !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:29:in `<main>'
remote:  !
remote: /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/helpers/rake_runner.rb:106:in `load_rake_tasks!': Could not detect rake tasks (LanguagePack::Helpers::RakeRunner::CannotLoadRakefileError)
```

I tried `bundle exec rake -P` locally:

```
➜  x git:(master) ✗ bundle exec rake -P
2019-11-03 17:38:37 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome#driver_path= is deprecated. Use Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Service#driver_path= instead.
rake aborted!
ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage
/Users/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:206:in `rescue in _decrypt'
/Users/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:183:in `_decrypt'
/Users/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:157:in `decrypt_and_verify'
/Users/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/messages/rotator.rb:21:in `decrypt_and_verify'
/Users/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:80:in `decrypt'
/Users/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:43:in `read'
/Users/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:21:in `read'
/Users/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:33:in `config'
/Users/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:38:in `options'
/Users/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb:297:in `method_missing'
/Users/xx/x/config/application.rb:14:in `<class:Application>'
/Users/xx/x/config/application.rb:9:in `<module:x>'
/Users/xx/x/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/xx/x/Rakefile:7:in `require_relative'
/Users/xx/x/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rake-13.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/Users/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'

Caused by:
OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError:
/Users/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:201:in `final'
/Users/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:201:in `_decrypt'
/Users/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:157:in `decrypt_and_verify'
/Users/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/messages/rotator.rb:21:in `decrypt_and_verify'
/Users/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:80:in `decrypt'
/Users/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:43:in `read'
/Users/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:21:in `read'
/Users/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:33:in `config'
/Users/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:38:in `options'
/Users/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb:297:in `method_missing'
/Users/x/x/config/application.rb:14:in `<class:Application>'
/Users/xx/x/config/application.rb:9:in `<module:x>'
/Users/xx/x/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/xx/x/Rakefile:7:in `require_relative'
/Users/xx/x/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rake-13.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/Users/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

But a command like `bundle exec rake db:migrate` is working.

This is my Gemfile.lock:

```
GIT
  remote: https://github.com/xxx/omniauth-oauth2
  revision: d78c9343eaf039e3cc1cae5779f3e70bab36c7ca
  specs:
    omniauth-oauth2 (1.5.0)
      oauth2 (~> 1.1)
      omniauth (~> 1.2)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (6.0.0)
      actionpack (= 6.0.0)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailbox (6.0.0)
      actionpack (= 6.0.0)
      activejob (= 6.0.0)
      activerecord (= 6.0.0)
      activestorage (= 6.0.0)
      activesupport (= 6.0.0)
      mail (>= 2.7.1)
    actionmailer (6.0.0)
      actionpack (= 6.0.0)
      actionview (= 6.0.0)
      activejob (= 6.0.0)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (6.0.0)
      actionview (= 6.0.0)
      activesupport (= 6.0.0)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.0)
    actiontext (6.0.0)
      actionpack (= 6.0.0)
      activerecord (= 6.0.0)
      activestorage (= 6.0.0)
      activesupport (= 6.0.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
    actionview (6.0.0)
      activesupport (= 6.0.0)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.1, >= 1.2.0)
    activejob (6.0.0)
      activesupport (= 6.0.0)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (6.0.0)
      activesupport (= 6.0.0)
    activerecord (6.0.0)
      activemodel (= 6.0.0)
      activesupport (= 6.0.0)
    activestorage (6.0.0)
      actionpack (= 6.0.0)
      activejob (= 6.0.0)
      activerecord (= 6.0.0)
      marcel (~> 0.3.1)
    activesupport (6.0.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.1, >= 2.1.8)
    addressable (2.5.2)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 4.0)
    airbrussh (1.4.0)
      sshkit (>= 1.6.1, != 1.7.0)
    archive-zip (0.12.0)
      io-like (~> 0.3.0)
    autoprefixer-rails (9.7.1)
      execjs
    bindex (0.8.1)
    bootsnap (1.4.5)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    bootstrap (4.3.1)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 9.1.0)
      popper_js (>= 1.14.3, < 2)
      sassc-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    builder (3.2.3)
    byebug (11.0.1)
    capistrano (3.11.2)
      airbrussh (>= 1.0.0)
      i18n
      rake (>= 10.0.0)
      sshkit (>= 1.9.0)
    capistrano-bundler (1.6.0)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
    capistrano-rails (1.4.0)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      capistrano-bundler (~> 1.1)
    capybara (3.29.0)
      addressable
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (~> 1.5)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    childprocess (3.0.0)
    chromedriver-helper (2.1.1)
      archive-zip (~> 0.10)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.5)
    crass (1.0.5)
    diff-lcs (1.3)
    domain_name (0.5.20190701)
      unf (>= 0.0.5, < 1.0.0)
    erubi (1.9.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    faraday (0.17.0)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
    ffi (1.11.1)
    foreman (0.86.0)
    genius (0.1.1)
      httparty (~> 0.11.0)
    globalid (0.4.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    hashie (3.6.0)
    http-cookie (1.0.3)
      domain_name (~> 0.5)
    httparty (0.11.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      multi_xml (>= 0.5.2)
    i18n (1.7.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    io-like (0.3.0)
    jbuilder (2.9.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    jquery-rails (4.3.5)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jwt (2.2.1)
    listen (3.2.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.10, >= 0.10.3)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.10)
    loofah (2.3.1)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (0.3.3)
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.2)
    method_source (0.9.2)
    mime-types (3.3)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2019.1009)
    mimemagic (0.3.3)
    mini_mime (1.0.2)
    mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
    minitest (5.13.0)
    msgpack (1.3.1)
    multi_json (1.14.1)
    multi_xml (0.6.0)
    multipart-post (2.1.1)
    net-scp (2.0.0)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5, < 6.0.0)
    net-ssh (5.2.0)
    netrc (0.11.0)
    nio4r (2.5.2)
    nokogiri (1.10.5)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.4.0)
    oauth2 (1.4.2)
      faraday (>= 0.8, < 2.0)
      jwt (>= 1.0, < 3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      multi_xml (~> 0.5)
      rack (>= 1.2, < 3)
    omniauth (1.9.0)
      hashie (>= 3.4.6, < 3.7.0)
      rack (>= 1.6.2, < 3)
    pg (1.1.4)
    popper_js (1.14.5)
    public_suffix (3.1.1)
    puma (4.2.1)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    rack (2.0.7)
    rack-proxy (0.6.5)
      rack
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (6.0.0)
      actioncable (= 6.0.0)
      actionmailbox (= 6.0.0)
      actionmailer (= 6.0.0)
      actionpack (= 6.0.0)
      actiontext (= 6.0.0)
      actionview (= 6.0.0)
      activejob (= 6.0.0)
      activemodel (= 6.0.0)
      activerecord (= 6.0.0)
      activestorage (= 6.0.0)
      activesupport (= 6.0.0)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 6.0.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.3.0)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    railties (6.0.0)
      actionpack (= 6.0.0)
      activesupport (= 6.0.0)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.20.3, < 2.0)
    rake (13.0.0)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
    rb-inotify (0.10.0)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    regexp_parser (1.6.0)
    rest-client (2.0.2)
      http-cookie (>= 1.0.2, < 2.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 4.0)
      netrc (~> 0.8)
    rspec-core (3.9.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.9.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.9.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.9.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.9.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.9.0)
    rspec-rails (3.9.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.9.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.9.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.9.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.9.0)
    rspec-support (3.9.0)
    rspotify (2.6.0)
      addressable (~> 2.5.2)
      omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.5.0)
      rest-client (~> 2.0.2)
    rubyzip (2.0.0)
    sassc (2.2.1)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
    sassc-rails (2.1.2)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
      sassc (>= 2.0)
      sprockets (> 3.0)
      sprockets-rails
      tilt
    selenium-webdriver (3.142.6)
      childprocess (>= 0.5, < 4.0)
      rubyzip (>= 1.2.2)
    slim (4.0.1)
      temple (>= 0.7.6, < 0.9)
      tilt (>= 2.0.6, < 2.1)
    slim-rails (3.2.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.1)
      railties (>= 3.1)
      slim (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
    spring (2.1.0)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (4.0.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sshkit (1.20.0)
      net-scp (>= 1.1.2)
      net-ssh (>= 2.8.0)
    temple (0.8.2)
    thor (0.20.3)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.10)
    turbolinks (5.2.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.2)
    turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
    twilio-ruby (5.29.0)
      faraday (~> 0.9)
      jwt (>= 1.5, <= 2.5)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6, < 2.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (4.2.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    unf (0.1.4)
      unf_ext
    unf_ext (0.0.7.6)
    web-console (4.0.1)
      actionview (>= 6.0.0)
      activemodel (>= 6.0.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    webpacker (4.0.7)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
      rack-proxy (>= 0.6.1)
      railties (>= 4.2)
    websocket-driver (0.7.1)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.4)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    zeitwerk (2.2.1)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  bootsnap (~> 1.4, >= 1.4.5)
  bootstrap (~> 4.3, >= 4.3.1)
  byebug
  capistrano-rails (~> 1.4)
  capybara (~> 3.29)
  chromedriver-helper (~> 2.1, >= 2.1.1)
  foreman (~> 0.86.0)
  genius (~> 0.1.1)
  jbuilder (~> 2.9, >= 2.9.1)
  jquery-rails (~> 4.3, >= 4.3.5)
  listen (~> 3.2)
  omniauth-oauth2!
  pg (>= 0.18, < 2.0)
  puma (~> 4.2, >= 4.2.1)
  rails (~> 6.0)
  rspec-rails (~> 3.9)
  rspotify (~> 2.6)
  sassc-rails (~> 2.1)
  selenium-webdriver (~> 3.142, >= 3.142.6)
  slim-rails (~> 3.2)
  spring (~> 2.1)
  spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.1)
  turbolinks (~> 5.2, >= 5.2.1)
  twilio-ruby (~> 5.29)
  uglifier (~> 4.2)
  web-console (~> 4.0, >= 4.0.1)
  webpacker (~> 4.0, >= 4.0.7)

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.6.3p62

BUNDLED WITH
   2.0.2
```

Any idea?

Comment: Did you add your master key to heroku? `heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=<your-master-key-here>`. The key can be found in `/config/master.key`. https://medium.com/cedarcode/rails-5-2-credentials-9b3324851336

Comment: Hi @max, I did it, but not effect. It's weird because I had the same error locally. I also tried to delete the keys and regenerate them